# FusionTablesLayer - Get Location column on click

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google Maps with a FusionTablesLayer showing railways in Germany (the fusion table can be found [here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1cVaJLbbxgBErP8PzYkHP-lpWMN8wUmINbdAJS1Y#rows%3aid=1)). The `geometry` column contains the LineString coordinates of each feature.

```
var railwaysLayer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    map: map,
    query: {
        select: 'geometry',
        from: '1cVaJLbbxgBErP8PzYkHP-lpWMN8wUmINbdAJS1Y'
    }
});
```

When a user clicks on a railway, i need to know which row (or feature actually) got clicked. This can be done in the `click` event handler like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(existingRailwaysLayer, 'click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.row.geometry.value);
});
```

This works as expected, but here's the problem: This table got uploaded one month ago from a KML file as a test. I've imported the exact same KML file on a different account today ([here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1QYZJq2xmUOVdwN3Rayv49vI6X-NUZZW7ZY1NwQs#rows%3aid=1)), and the `geometry` column isn't being returned anymore in the event handler.

I checked all the settings and found out that in both tables, the `geometry` columns are of type `Location`. However: in the first table, the rows are NOT geocoded. `File > Geocode > Begin geocoding` effectively starts the process of geocoding each row, while in the second table it says: 'Column is fully geocoded'.

Since everything else is exactly the same, this could very well be the problem. I don't know how to 'un-geocode' the rows in the second table. Since the first one got uploaded a month ago, my guess is that Google now automatically geocodes the rows.

Is there any way to get the `geometry` column of the feature that got clicked?

Note: It's definitely possible, even when the `geometry`column is geocoded. In the 'Map of geometry' tab of the second table, you can select the columns that are shown in the infoWindow when a feature is clicked. See [here](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1QYZJq2xmUOVdwN3Rayv49vI6X-NUZZW7ZY1NwQs#map%3aid=3) for a working demo.

Answer (score 0):

rows with KML-data will not be included in rows (I'm not sure if this always has been).

I guess the KML-features have been ommitted to save bandwidth

What you can do:

Parse `e.infoWindowHtml` (as you have noticed it's possible to print the geometry-feature in the InfoWindow, `e.infoWindowHtml` contains the string used as content for the InfoWindow).

But the automatic InfoWindow-template only shows the coordinates, use a dynamic template, e.g.

```
{template .contents}
<div class='googft-info-window'>
<b>description:</b> {$data.formatted.description}<br>
<b>name:</b> {$data.formatted.name}<br>
<div style="width:0;height:0;overflow:hidden;">[[{$data.value.geometry}]]</div>
</div>
{/template}
```

(You may use this template with your table, I've created it, it has the `templateId:6`)

As you can see the geometry is embedded in a div with no size, yit will not be shown inside the InfoWindow.
The geometry is enclosed by square brackets, use RegExp to find it:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(railwaysLayer, 'click', function(e) {

  var str = e.infoWindowHtml, geo;

  if(geo=str.match(/\[\[([^\]]+)]]/)){
      geo=geo[1].replace(/(&gt;|&lt;)/g,function(x){
            return((x==='&gt;')?'>':'<');
          });
      console.log(geo);
  }
});
```

Demo:(using your table with my template) [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/9YdKW/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/9YdKW/)

Comment: This was also my first idea, but as you know, this is not a solid solution. It's doomed to break at some point in time (if Google updates the FusionTablesLayer InfoWindow). That's why i chose to add an extra column which holds the exact same details as the `geometry`column, except that it's of type 'text'. I know this adds up to the total size, but it seemed like a more solid solution.

Comment: I wouldn't call the adding of a column-copy more solid. A more solid solution would be to give the columns an unique id and request the geometry via AJAX.